# Why is the EventBus event on my Fragment not working?

Tags: java, android

I have 3 events on my Fragment. It reads the other 2 events, aside from the event I added a new event. Why is it not reading that event?

I have the following code. On my ProductListActivity.class, I have registered my eventbus. I also registered it on ProductListFragment.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        eventBus.register(this);
    }

private void onSort(String productSortType) {

    switch (ProductSortValueType.valueOf(productSortType)) {

        case PROMOTIONS_FIRST:
            eventBus.postOnMain(new ProductArrangement(ProductSortValueType.PROMOTIONS_FIRST));
            break;
        case LOWEST_PRICE:
            eventBus.postOnMain(new ProductArrangement(ProductSortValueType.LOWEST_PRICE));
            break;
        default:
            eventBus.postOnMain(new ProductArrangement(ProductSortValueType.POPULARITY));
    }
}
```

> This is the event that I am trying to call on ProductListFragment. But it is not working.

```
@Subscribe
public void onProductArrangementReceiver(ProductArrangement productArrangement) {

    switch (productArrangement.productSortValueType) {

        case PROMOTIONS_FIRST:
            controller.get_product_by_aisle(aisle.id, "fmcg-campaign.status=active,-percent-off,-buy-x-take-y,-monthly-popular-score", PAGE, SIZE, String.format("%s_%s", aisle.attributes.name, aisle.id));
            break;
        case LOWEST_PRICE:
            controller.get_product_by_aisle(aisle.id, "fmcg-campaign.status=active,amount-in-cents,-monthly-popular-score", PAGE, SIZE, String.format("%s_%s", aisle.attributes.name, aisle.id));
            break;
        default:
            controller.get_product_by_aisle(aisle.id, "fmcg-campaign.status=active,-monthly-popular-score", PAGE, SIZE, String.format("%s_%s", aisle.attributes.name, aisle.id));
    }
}
```

> This is my ProductArrangement.class.

```
 @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            eventBus.register(this);
        }
public class ProductArrangement {

    public ProductSortValueType productSortValueType;
    public String filterBrandId;

    public ProductArrangement(ProductSortValueType productSortValueType) {
        this.productSortValueType = productSortValueType;
    }

    public ProductArrangement() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have register eventbus in ProductListFragment?

Comment: Yes. It is registered under `onResume()` method in ProductListFragment .

Comment: share your code

Comment: @NensiKasundra I already edited it.